# Why is the MAC address I get in code different from the actual MAC address in Linux

Tags: python

```
import uuid
uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode()).hex[-12:]
```

When I execute the code on the python command line, what I get is not the MAC address of `eth0`, but the MAC address of a docker network card. There is no such problem on other machines.

Comment: Are you running it in Docker…?

Comment: Why do you care?  That's never been a proper way to get your MAC address.

Comment: *"“Hardware address” means the MAC address of a network interface. On a machine with multiple network interfaces, universally administered MAC addresses (i.e. where the second least significant bit of the first octet is unset) will be preferred over locally administered MAC addresses, but with no other ordering guarantees."*

Comment: No, I execute commands in the basic Python environment of Linux.

Comment: I run the same code on other Ubuntu and CentOS machines, and the MAC addresses returned are correct and consistent. I don't quite understand why the current machine will return me the MAC address of docker network@TimRoberts

Comment: This MAC address is out of order, isn't it?@deceze

Comment: `uuid.getnode` isn’t the most reliable way to get the MAC of a *specific* network interface. It just gives you *a* MAC with no control over which exactly. If that’s not good enough for you, you need to more explicitly interrogate available network interfaces yourself and pick the right one.